# Windows - Cygwin - Vim - Python - Import errors

Tags: python, vim, matplotlib, cygwin

I am a novice coder trying to learn python27. I am using windows 8.1, cygwin, and Vim74 (running from cygwin command line). When executing this simple script...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 8, 12])
plt.title('title')
plt.show()
```

...from the cygwin command line or from VIM running within cygwin, I am returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

When I execute the script from the windows command line it works just fine and the correct graph appears. I know there are many similar questions pertaining to this type of error, however, nothing I've tried has worked so far... I'm sure it is something simple... Or maybe not. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

-Red

Comment: what's the output of `where python`

Comment: `$ where python`
`C:\cygwin\bin\python`
`C:\Python27\python.exe`
`C:\program files\User\Scripts\python.exe`
`C:\Program Files\User\python.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the cygwin version of python, which doesn't have the matplotlib library. You need to tell cygwin that when you run the `python` command, you want the windows version of Python. Add this line to your `.bashrc` file.

```
alias python='/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe'
```

If you don't know what your `.bashrc` file is, just type

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

and you'll be editing it. Add the above line at the bottom of the file, Then re-source it. To do this, type

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

The problem of running from Vim still remains: if you're using the cygwin version of vim, then it will use the cygwin path, but none of the aliases. Try this mapping to fix that (add to your `~/.vimrc` file):

```
au Filetype python nnoremap <leader>r :w !/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe %<CR>
```

You should now be able to run the current python script with `<leader>r` If you don't have a leader key, it's backslash, so the command would be `\r`

If you're not too committed to cygwin vim however, I would suggest getting a windows build of vim and using gVim for all your editing needs. Things like this don't get easier with time, they just get more and more complicated as you want to do more and more things.

Comment: Thats fantastic! Thank you. It works now from the cygwin console, however one issue still remains... When I open the file in VIM, from the cygwin console, and then run the file using `w !python` I am returned the same error as before. Maybe VIM doesnt know where python is???

Comment: Edited to answer that question.

Comment: Hummm, I copied and pasted directly into `~/.vimrc` and still getting the same error... Any potential tweaks to the former?

Comment: How do I know if I have a leader key? Are you saying `\r` would now be the command in VIM to execute the file instead of `:w !python`? I definitely get your drift, this "ugly" situation is temporary and I will hopefully be living in Ubuntu soon :)

Comment: If you don't have the line `let mapleader = "SOMETHING"` in your `.vimrc`, then your leader will default to backslash. Yes, as you guessed, you will now be able to run a python script with the shortcut `\r`. It's just easier and fewer keypresses, and that's what vim is all about. Here's a short article on the leader key http://usevim.com/2012/07/20/vim101-leader/